# Transforming TEI p into lg

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, tei

I have TEI (text encoding initiative) document containing

```
<div>
  <p>
     some text, and maybe nodes <note>A note</note><lb />
     and some more text<lb />
     final line without lb
  </p>
</div>
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
<div>
  <lg>
     <l>some text, and maybe nodes <note>A note</note></l>
     <l>and some more text</l>
     <l>final line without lb</l>
  </lg>
</div>
```

Transforming the p to lg is trivial by using

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div/tei:p">
   <lg>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </lg>
</xsl:template>
```

But the rest can't i figure out how to do. Turning a sequence of nodes into children of a new parent.

If there is a solution for xslt 1.0 would it be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a technique called [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) here. In this case, you can group the child nodes of a `p` element by the number of `lb` elements that follow them

```
<xsl:key name="p-nodes" match="tei:p/node()" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb))" />
```

To get the first node in each group, which will represent each `l` you want outputted, you would select them like so...

```
<xsl:for-each
     select="node()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('p-nodes', concat($parentId, '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb)))[1])]">
```

And to output the `<l>` tag itself and the contents of the group, use the key again...

```
<l><xsl:apply-templates select="key('p-nodes', concat($parentId, '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb)))[not(self::tei:lb)]" /></l>
```

Try this XSLT (obviously changing the namespace for the `tei` prefix to match the real one in your XML)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:tei="tei">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="p-nodes" match="tei:p/node()" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb))" />

    <xsl:template match="tei:div/tei:p">
       <lg>
            <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="generate-id()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="node()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('p-nodes', concat($parentId, '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb)))[1])]">
                <l><xsl:apply-templates select="key('p-nodes', concat($parentId, '|', count(following-sibling::tei:lb)))[not(self::tei:lb)]" /></l>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </lg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/gWEamMf

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot @tim-c :) I think I have a lot more to learn about xslt.

Comment: You might want to look at michael.hor257K's answer too. It is neater and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could look at it. It uses a **key** to link every node to its nearest preceding `lb` separator. This enables you to fetch every group (except the very first one) by the unique id of the leading separator:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="following-nodes" match="node()[not(self::lb)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::lb[1])" />

<xsl:template match="p[lb]">
    <lg>
        <l>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="lb[1]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
        </l>
        <xsl:for-each select="lb">
            <l>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('following-nodes', generate-id())"/>
            </l>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </lg>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This example uses no namespaces, because your question does not define them.

Comment: Thanks a lot @michael.hor257k :) I feel really like a newbee on xslt. And this was about the first thing I had to achive.